# Determine all pairs of prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Determine all pairs of prime numbers $(m,n)$ satisfying
$$(7m-n)^2=2(m-1)n^2$$

Comment: Have you tried anything? What can you say about the factors of the left-hand side?

Comment: $n\mid (7m-n)^2$, so $n\mid (7m)^2$, so $n\in\{7,m\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be fun to try:

An equivalent formulation of your problem is the following: determine all pairs of prime numbers $(m,n)$ satisfying
$$
\left(7\frac{m}{n}-1\right)^2=2(m-1).
$$
The number on the left is clearly rational; however, the only rationals that square to integers are integers. So if $(m,n)$ solves the original equation, then $7m/n$ must be an integer. Since $m$ and $n$ must be prime, this means that $n=7$ or $m=n$. If you assume that $n=7$, the original equation reduces to a quadratic polynomial in $m$; any roots of that polynomial which are prime will solve your problem. The same is true if $m=n$.

Edit: I was being super lazy, and ended up suggesting a course of action that is more work than you should do; plug $n=7$ into the original equation, factor, and cancel. This leaves a linear equation, which is much nicer! The same holds true if you plug in $m=n$. This yields the solutions $(3,7)$ and $(19,19)$.

Answer (score 1):

$2 (m - 1)$ is square, so let $m = 2 k^2 + 1$, hence $(7 m - n)^2 = (2 k
n)^2$. Suppose $7 m - n = 2 k n$, then $7 m = (2 k + 1) n$. Since $m, n$ are
prime, either $n = 7$ or $2 k + 1 = 7$, so $n = 7, m = 3$ or $n = 19, m = 19$. Suppose $7 m - n = - 2 k n$, then $7 m = (1 - 2 k) n$, but $k \geqslant 1$,
contradiction.